# How do I update a BIT column from VBA using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

This looks like it should be so simple, but ... When I set a value in my 2nd parameter I get an error, 3421, telling me that my "value is the wrong type".

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emails]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [ManagerList] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [FixtureList] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [Shomatch] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [Newsletter] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [Turn] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [Started] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [Sent] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [Acknowledged] BIT NOT NULL, 
    [League] INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Emails_League] FOREIGN KEY ([League]) REFERENCES [Leagues]([Id]) 
)
```

This is my stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmails]
    @pLeagueId INT,
    @pFixtureList BIT
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[Emails]
    SET [FixtureList] = @pFixtureList
    WHERE [League] = @pLeagueId;
```

This is my code :

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Option Compare Text

Sub UpdateEmailsFixtureList()

Set KA_Com = New ADODB.Command

KA_Com.CommandText = "UpdateEmails"
KA_Com.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set KA_Parameter = KA_Com.CreateParameter(Name:="pLeagueId", Type:=adInteger)

KA_Com.Parameters.Append KA_Parameter
KA_Com.Parameters("pLeagueId").Value = KA_RS_Leagues![ID]

Set KA_Parameter = KA_Com.CreateParameter(Name:="pFixtureList", Type:=adBinary, Size:=1)

KA_Com.Parameters.Append KA_Parameter
KA_Com.Parameters("pFixtureList").Value = 1 <<< ERROR 3421 on this line

Set KA_RS_Leagues = KA_Com.Execute

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help, I can't understand how something that looks so simple can be so stubborn !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the Parameter as Bit, change it to Char and Pass change your Procedure as Below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmails]
    @pLeagueId int,
    @pFixtureList char(1)

AS

    UPDATE [dbo].[Emails]

    SET [FixtureList] = CASE @pFixtureList WHEN '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    WHERE [League] = @pLeagueId;

    GO
```

Comment: That worked, superb, thank you, but why ?!? I mean, if you have to be so explicit when defining Columns and DataTypes why does the system not work when you actually use them ?!?!? MS can be very bizarre sometimes !!!

Answer (score 0):

Pass value to `true` OR `false`, as your type is `BIT` in database/sp (@pFixtureList bit) it will accept `true/false` as value and display `1/0` in table respectively.

```
KA_Com.Parameters("pFixtureList").Value = true;
```

Comment: when you pass true/false your parameter must remain same : `@pFixtureList BIT`